# how to parse and extract specific fields and store it into another field in logstash filter?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, filebeat

I have application log files which are shipped to the logstash using Filebeat. the log file will have content something like this, with module name and the time taken to process in it

```
[10/08/2020#11:25:45:451] #SVS#SVS#NA#NA#NA#-#DE#00000199#DE_ONL_DC_SERVER1_NODE05_PRD##[8/10/2020#11:25:45:451] #O#-#-#-#Module1#1#-#5#-#-#-#CoreB#-
```

I want to extract only 3 fields from the above log, the modulename {Module1} , Time taken to process{5}, Server Name{DE_ONL_DC_SERVER1_NODE05_PRD} , so that I can plot them into a dashboard of those terms in kibana.

I am quite new to the elk stack and still exploring on the various filter options in logfilter to achieve the above, Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So, i have found Dissect filter would be ideal for the above use case. anyhow if anyone has a better approach, pls do help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly, if all your log lines look exactly the same, I would leverage the [`dissect` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html). A pattern like this one should do:

```
filter {
  dissect {
    mapping => {
      "message" => "[%{@timestamp}] #%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}#-#%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}#%{serverName}##[%{?ignored}] #%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}#%{moduleName}#%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}#%{processTime}#%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}#%{?ignored}
"
    }
  }
}
```

This would extract the following fields into the event:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "10/08/2020#11:25:45:451",
    "message": "[10/08/2020#11...",
    "serverName": "DE_ONL_DC_SERVER1_NODE05_PRD",
    "moduleName": "Module1",
    "processTime": 5
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but does the dissection mean the message field will be updated with the  mapping or, we will have to mutate, because, i am observing the output in kibana is still the same full message as before. Thanks in advance

Comment: The message field doesn't change, the dissect filter is only extracting data from it into new fields.

Comment: Understood, so we will have to use the mutate to add the newly extracted fields into the message. Got it. Thank you

Comment: No, dissect will add the fields itself, no need for mutate. See at the bottom of my answer, this is what you'll get in your documents.

Comment: Atlast after struggling from yesterday , found due to couple of issues ( the condition in filter was wrong, wrong conf file ) - i am able to get the fields in the kibana. Thank you